# QT5: QPSQL driver not loaded

Tags: c++, postgresql, visual-studio, qt

I had a simple database initialization code using postgres sql

```
#include <QtSql>
#include <QApplication>

int main()
{
 QSqlDatabase *testdb = new QSqlDatabase;
 QString databaseName = "mydatabase";
 *testdb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QString("QPSQL"), databaseName);
 ....
 return 0; }
```

When i tried to execute it says
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Is there any way to fix this problem?
I am using
Qt 5.8.0
msvc2015_64
Visual Studio 2015
postgres 15.2 64-bit

I've seen quite a lot of solution but it all doesnt seems to work for me

Comment: Find the DLL file responsible for it and see if dependency walker is happy with it? Also Qt 5.8 is ancient, you should upgrade to 5.15.

Comment: [I've seen quite a lot of solution but it all doesnt seems to work for me] -> What were these solutions you tried?

Comment: Hi both, I tried to use depends.exe for qsqlpsql.dll and it showed that it requires Qt5core.dll,Qt5Gui.dll and LIBPQ.dll to execute. Hence i put all these 3 DLL into the C://Qt5.8.0/5.8/msvc2015_64/plugins/sqldrivers folder but it does not work

Comment: 1 out of the 3 DLLs you listed is incorrect though... and the folder is incorrect too. `qsqlpsql.dll` must be save in a `sqldrivers` folder created next to your executable and the other 3 DLLs must be saved in the same folder as your executable.

Comment: I managed to get it fixed by adding libiconv-2.dll, libcrypto01_1x64.dll, libintl-9.dll, libql.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll. Thanks a lot